# SCRIPT1002/1010 error in IE11 using polyfills

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, babeljs

I'm using Typescript + React + Webpack stack (for ts/tsx files I have `awesome-typescript-loader`). I'm trying to run my app on IE11 but I got a problems in IE debugger.

Debugger shows SCRIPT1002 @ first line and it's line with arrow function. I handled it by add:

```
require('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread');
require('@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions');
require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');
```

to polyfills.js file in config dir. My `webpack.config.prod.js` contains:

`entry: [require.resolve('./polyfills'), paths.appIndexJs],`

and polyfills.js:

```
require('@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread');
require('@babel/plugin-transform-arrow-functions');
require('@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties');

'use strict';

if (typeof Promise === 'undefined') {
  // Rejection tracking prevents a common issue where React gets into an
  // inconsistent state due to an error, but it gets swallowed by a Promise,
  // and the user has no idea what causes React's erratic future behavior.
  require('promise/lib/rejection-tracking').enable();
  window.Promise = require('promise/lib/es6-extensions.js');
}

// fetch() polyfill for making API calls.
require('whatwg-fetch');

// Object.assign() is commonly used with React.
// It will use the native implementation if it's present and isn't buggy.
Object.assign = require('object-assign');

// In tests, polyfill requestAnimationFrame since jsdom doesn't provide it yet.
// We don't polyfill it in the browser--this is user's responsibility.
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test') {
  require('raf').polyfill(global);
}
```

After this SCRIPT1002 I'm getting SCRIPT1010 error as on image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgHly.png

and I stuck. Any ideas?